# GZip HttpServletResponse in Servlet Filter based on "Content-Length"

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a specific requirement to Zip the HttpServletResponse based on the content length. The application I am working on is Spring based and exposes several services with JSON payload. However some of the payloads are quite huge in size ~2MB but are not consistently so i.e. are dependent on responses from external systems.

I have tried searching but could only succeed in Zipping based on URL mappings and not based on actual size of the payload. The server used is weblogic but does not support the GZIP configuration and hence looking to achieve this through Servlet Filter. Following is the code from my filter that I have so far but doesn't seem to be working. Any pointers in how to achieve dynamic GZipping based on the Content-Length and what would be the best way to do so?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest paramServletRequest, ServletResponse paramServletResponse, FilterChain paramFilterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ((paramServletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        HttpServletRequest localHttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) paramServletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse localHttpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) paramServletResponse;

        if (supportsGzip(localHttpServletRequest)) {
            // This block is where response is being validated for
            // eligibility of compression based on "Content-Length" header
            paramFilterChain.doFilter(paramServletRequest, localHttpServletResponse);
            String contentLengthString = localHttpServletResponse.getHeader("Content-Length");
            int contentLength = contentLengthString != null && !contentLengthString.isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt(contentLengthString) : 0;

            //GZip only if the content length is greater than 750 KB 
            if (contentLength > (750*1024)) {
                System.out.println("This should be zipped content");
                localHttpServletResponse = new GZipResponseWrapper(localHttpServletResponse);
                localHttpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                ((GZipResponseWrapper)localHttpServletResponse).finishResponse();
                return;
            }
        }

        paramFilterChain.doFilter(paramServletRequest, paramServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Quite new to the forum and apologize in advance for any incorrect formats / structure.

Comment: Is the content simply not zipped or is there an error?  Why not just gzip everything text based and not worry about the length (see, for example, [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html) for an example of configuring compression based on content type)?

Comment: There lies the problem. In most of the cases the response payload will be less than 1KB. These responses are not to be compressed is a requirement that I am trying to deal with and have issues with it. So just wanted to check if there is any way to overwrite the ServletOutputStream by converting it to GZipOutputStream in a filter.
There is no error with the above code except that the Response does not contain anything at all i.e there is no payload cause the write was done on ServletOutputStream while the GZipOutputStream which was empty was returned/written I guess.